# SQL Server - How can I select the first row with the word "Rehired" that shows up after the last row with the word "Quit"

Tags: sql-server-2000

```
Date..............Comment1............................Comment2
20041206.....Address change from/to:........616 Barry Road Apt
20050314.....Rehired on Mar 14/05............Rehired on Mar 14/05
20051117.....Terminated on Nov17/05.......Shortage of Work
20060131.....Address change from/to:........616 Barry Road Apt
20060410.....Rehired on Apr 10/06   ............Pay Rate change    
20060419.....Vac. pay owing: from..............changed by 
20060531.....Terminated on May31/06........Quit
20070208.....Address change from/to:........11 Bettley Court
20080921.....Rehired on Sep 21/08............Pay Rate change    <== this row
20080925.....Vac. pay owing:.....................from   
20090215.....Pay Rate change...................0.00
20090712.....Pay Rate change...................0.000
```

I want to end up with the Date (20080921) from the indicated record .

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  Date > (SELECT TOP 1 Date
               FROM   YourTable
               WHERE  ( Comment1 LIKE '%Quit%'
                         OR Comment2 LIKE '%Quit%' )
               ORDER  BY Date DESC)
       AND ( Comment1 LIKE '%Rehired%'
              OR Comment2 LIKE '%Rehired%' )
ORDER  BY Date
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for the records I posted which is for one employee (I had to add brackets around (Comment1 LIKE '%Rehired%' 
        OR Comment2 LIKE '%Rehired%')). Now I would need to do this for each employee in the table?  So each employee will have multiple records like the above posted. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I guess you did have the brackets or added them. :)

Answer (score 0):

A little rough, but:

```
SELECT t2.DATE
FROM TABLE t1 INNER JOIN
     TABLE t2 on t1.Date < t2.Date LEFT OUTER JOIN
     TABLE t3 on t1.Date < t3.Date AND t3.Date < t2.Date AND t3.Comment1 LIKE 'Rehired%' LEFT OUTER JOIN
     TABLE t4 on t4.Date > t1.Date and t4.Comment2 = 'Quit'
WHERE t1.Comment2 = 'Quit'
AND t2.Comment1 like 'Rehired%'
AND t3.Date = null
AND t4.Date = null
```

t1 is your quit record and t2 is your rehired record.  t3 ensures no other rehired occurs between t1 and t2, and t4 ensures no other quit occurs after t1.   Therefore, t2 is the firstmost rehired after the lastmost quit.

Comment: AND t3 = null 
AND t4 = null gives me an invalid column name

Comment: Sorry, that should be `t3.date = null and t4.date = null`. (Actually, you can use any field, because it will still be null.)  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Date format could be tricky, but try like this.

```
declare @LastDate datetime
set @LastDate='2008/09/21'

select date,comment1,comment2 from your table 
where cast(date as datetime)>=@LastDate 
order by date
```